# when i am trying to deploy my django project on heroku server these errors are showing so please give any ans

Tags: heroku-cli, django-deployment, deploying

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1

ERROR: "Failed building wheel for backports.zoneinfo",

ERROR: "Could not build wheels for backports.zoneinfo",

which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.

! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/image456.git'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say create a *runtime.txt* file in the root folder, and in the file, change the python version because it's the problem of Heroku. Python 3.10.3 has lots of bugs, so I'd suggest switching to Python 3.8. To do so, create a *runtime.txt* file, then in it, write *python-3.8.13* without any spaces. Then delete and redo 'git init', 'git add .' and the stuff that you previously did before the 'git push heroku master'. I had the same problem myself, and I did exactly that (I was using Python 3.8).

If you don't like Python 3.8.13, there's Python 3.7.13, and 3.9.11. The format for them are *python-3.7.13* *python-3.9.11*

Comment: yes your ans is absolutely right thank you so much for gave the right solution